# Как построить пешеходный маршрут yandex mapKit android

Tags: android, kotlin, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Я пытаюсь реализовать построение пешеходного маршрута при помощи яндекс карт в своем android приложении , я использую этот пример https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/yandex/mapkitdemo/MasstransitRoutingActivity.java , только меняю роутер на PedestrianRouter , но сталкиваюсь с ошибкой

> yandex::maps::mapkit::images::PolylineImageAtlas::add: Width of
> pattern is equal to 268, but should be power of 2. Added transparent
> padding

я предпололжил что не правильно заменяю роутер , но если я просто использую приведенный пример все равно эта ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения мне потребовалось немного изменить код представленный в примере, который был указан в описании вопроса

```
private fun drawSection(
    data: SectionMetadata.SectionData,
    geometry: Polyline
) {
    val polylineMapObject = mapObjects!!.addPolyline(geometry)
    if (data.transports == null) {
        polylineMapObject.setStrokeColor(R.color.main_blue)
    }
}
```

И я изменил роутер

```
mtRouter = TransportFactory.getInstance().createPedestrianRouter()
mtRouter!!.requestRoutes(points, TimeOptions(), this)
```

Все остальное осталось как в примере